# How can I disable a task in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I want to skip some tasks when I run `gradle build`. I know that it can be done from command line with `-x`:

```sh
gradle build -x unwantedTask
```

My question is how can the same result be achieved in the build.gradle?

Comment: I don't think you can edit the `build` task in the gradle file. You need to create your own task.

Answer (score 70):

You can try e.g.:

```
unwantedTask.enabled = false
```

Comment: Please note, that this will skip the task, which is not the same as using the `-x` option, but it should result in the desired behaviour. The exclusion of a task is only possible in the `settings.gradle` via `startParameter.excludedTaskNames`.

Comment: Could not set unknown property 'enabled' for extension 'jib' of type com.google.cloud.tools.jib.gradle.JibExtension.

Comment: Yes. For the next person who sees this, some extensions create tasks with the same name as another object and presumably Gradle/Groovy uses the other object first. To reference the task, use `tasks.jib.enabled = false`

Comment: For Gradle 4.9 or never one should use `tasks.named('jib') { enabled = false }` as this approach is lazy and does not trigger creation of `jib` task on before any Gradle task start.

Answer (score 33):

Because I need to disable a bunch of tasks, so I use the following codes before `apply plugin:` in my `build.gradle` file:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded {task ->
    if(task.name.contains("unwantedTask")) {
        task.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Only *this* solution worked for tasks, which are not always present (such as `startScripts` or `distZip`).

Comment: For all modules wrap it in `subprojects { ... }` and put it in root project `build.gradle`.

Comment: Didn't work. The task still appears in the gradle list :(

Comment: @EugenPechanec it seems you need to add this event after the task graph is populated with tasks. AFAIR you can try this way: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html#whenReady-groovy.lang.Closure-

Answer (score 25):

For a bit more generic approach, you can:

```
unwantedTask.onlyIf { <expression> }
```

For instance:

```
compileJava.onlyIf { false }
```

Advanced IDEs, like IDEA, through code completion, will give you a lots of what you can do on any given object in the `build.gradle` - it's just a Groovy script, after all.

Comment: This should be used with great attention since it may break gradle up-to-date mechanism.

Comment: TBH, after 6 years of experience with Gradle, I think that anything can break anything. A 2 years old Gradle build code rarely works (unlike Maven).

Answer (score 21):

As hinted to by @LukasKörfer in a comment, to really remove a task from the build, instead of just skipping it, one solution is to add this to your build script:

```
project.gradle.startParameter.excludedTaskNames.add('yourTaskName')
```

However this seems to remove the task for all subprojects.

Comment: Any name added to `excludedTaskNames` is interpreted in the same way as tasks passed to Gradle via the command line. Tasks names (`'yourTaskName'`) represent all tasks with the the name in all (sub-)projects, whereas task paths (`':yourTaskName'` or `':yourProject:yourTaskName'`) represent a single task.

Comment: FYI, there is also a bug related to this approach on Gradle version 6.8+:
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/18196

Answer (score 4):

Examples for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts):

```kotlin
tasks.clean {
    isEnabled = false
}
```

Another way:

```
tasks.getByName("MyTaskName") {
    onlyIf { 2 * 2 == 4 }
    // Another example: check whether there is an environment variable called CI with value true
    // onlyIf { System.getenv()["CI"] == "true" }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
project.gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
  project.tasks.findAll().forEach { task ->
    if (task.name.contains("<your-text>")) {
      task.enabled = false
    }
  }
}
```