# How to hide gradle task?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have defined few custom build tasks, which set few configuration properties and generate builds for different environments. Tasks are below:

```
val buildStage by tasks.registering {
    doFirst {
        val profile = "stage"
        println("spring.profiles.active = $profile")
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", profile)
        buildDir = File("${rootDir}/build/${profile}")
        tasks.withType<ProcessResources> {
            exclude("**/*.properties")
        }
    }
    finalizedBy(tasks.getByName("build"))
}

val buildProd by tasks.registering {
    doFirst {
        val profile = "prod"
        println("spring.profiles.active = $profile")
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", profile)
        buildDir = File("${rootDir}/build/${profile}")
        tasks.withType<ProcessResources> {
            exclude("**/*.properties")
        }
    }

    finalizedBy(tasks.getByName("build"))
}
```

How can I ensure that `gradle build` command is not directly invokable?

Is it possible to do something like:

```
tasks.getByName("build") {
    doFirst {
        if (System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active").isNullOrBlank()) {
            println("task not allowed")
            exitProcess(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see [How to disable a gradle task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47192746/how-can-i-disable-a-task-in-build-gradle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your current approach is that the `doFirst` closure of your `build` task will still execute after the tasks `build` depends on (e.g. `assemble`, `test`, `jar` ...), causing Gradle to fail when all the actual work is already done.

You may check whether the task `build` was called from the command line using the example below, but all these approaches to disable a task are just ugly hacks.

```kotlin
if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("build") {
    throw new GradleException("Task 'build' must not be called directly");
}
```

Instead, you should analyze your project and check which tasks actually require the configuration properties that belong to the different profiles. Afterwards setup your tasks and connect them using `dependsOn` / `finalizedBy` / `mustRunAfter` in a way that the build only fails when it needs to (because properties are not defined) and operates as expected otherwise.

The task `build` is the default task for the majority of Gradle projects. Your approach may confuse other developers interacting with your project, as calling `./gradlew build` is probably the very first thing to do on a new project.

Comment: Disabling the `build` task seems like creating problem indeed. Rather set some default environments for the `build` should be a good way. Thanks for the idea @lukas-körfer